# C# http Get request error

Tags: c#, httprequest

> *An error occurred while sending the request   - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.*

both the web project and the services are on localhost

Get request goes here -

```
    public static T Get<T>(string urlRequest, out string message) where T : class ,new() 
    {
        T result = default(T);

        string executionMessage = "";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var task = client.GetAsync(urlRequest)
            .ContinueWith((r) =>
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                response = r.Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    // convert response to CLR object
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    executionMessage = response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            });
            task.Wait();
        }

        message = executionMessage;
        return result;
    }
```

Any possible solutions for this problem?

Comment: please show urlRequest. Any more details?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Which line throws?

Comment: How big is the data being received and how much is the timeout on the server?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with above code. Have you tried making same request from the browser and checked that end server is reachable and serving the request properly.

Comment: I got the issue here, essentially, there was a change in port for the service project which resulted in ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes. I resolved it with http://forums.asp.net/t/1843393.aspx?+Fiddler+ReadResponse+failed+The+server+did+not+return+a+response+for+this+request+  Thanks for looking into this.